# Magento 2 - Override phtml files not working

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, catalog

I am working on Magento 2 and I override few PHTML files from

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/vendor/module/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml

From few days my `app/design > items.phtml` not working, showing vendor `items.phtml` layout. Working fine before.

I also run all these commands.

```
php magento setup:upgrade  
php magento setup:di:compile  
php magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php magento indexer:reindex  
php magento cache:flush
```

Please help?

Comment: Is your theme active?

Comment: Yes, theme is active.

Comment: check any custom module use this file ?

Comment: @RkRathod. Yes I found this file in a module, which uses default vendor file, not my theme file.

Comment: Module name is WeltPixel GoogleTag Manager.

Comment: as you say this file is used by WeltPixel module, as Module priority is higher file must be call from module, whatever ever changes you want do in modules item.phtml file

Answer (score 1):

Below will work fine:

**YourThemesVendor** = your theme **vendorname** e.g. Mine is "pearl"

**YourThemeNamespace =** your theme **themename** e.g. Mine is "customize"

> app/design/frontend/YourThemesVendor/YourThemeNamespace/Magento_Catalog
>   /templates/product/list/items.phtml

Answer (score 0):

### **In Your Theme**

> If you want to override in your **theme** then create a following
>   directory structure

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list
```

> Copy **items.phtml** file from below path

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

> You can also override Layout file **catalog_product_view.xml** from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout` to your
>   theme and make the changes you wish.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
```

### **In your Module**

> If you want to override in your **Module** then create a following
>   directory structure

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list
```

> Copy **items.phtml** file from below path

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

> Override Layout file **catalog_product_view.xml** from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout` to your
>   module and make the changes you wish.

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout
```

**Remove Cache**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: Directory structure is same as you mention above.I already said that every thing is working perfect from few days ago.

Comment: please look closely, your second path is not correct if you're implementing in theme

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RkRathod to pointing me.
I have found solution of my answer.Actually I am using `Google Tag Manager` extension which is using this template. So this module was override my items file.I just replaced with my theme items file and issue resolved.